# Firefox add-on get the tab body content

Tags: tabs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Hello everyone i have an question about firefox add-on:

How i can get the body content from a tab, for example.

```
var content = require("tabs").activeTab.documentContent.body.innerHTML;
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: Did you find out if it works with the SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Add-on SDK doesn't allow direct access to the tab contents - the idea is that the add-on and the tab might end up living in different processes eventually. What you do is injecting a content script into the tab to get you the necessary data, something like this:

```js
var tab = require("tabs").activeTab;
tab.attach({
  contentScript: "self.postMessage(document.body.innerHTML);",
  onMessage: function(data)
  {
    console.log("Tab data received: " + data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect example, how to do that whitout postMessage message? (No show the message in the page).

Comment: You don't, as I said you cannot access the tab contents directly - at least not when using official APIs.

Comment: Ok, perefect...
How i can close that message wen appears?

Comment: Marcos: unsure what you mean - postmessage will not display anything to the user.

Comment: Okey, sorry... I was off for a while in the page. As I see in another posts SDP (Same domain policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) affects in this case. The only way to get the content is modify the document whit the plugin to alert the document content.

Comment: @WladimirPalantᛜ I'm getting `ReferenceError: require is not defined` for line `require("tabs")`

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: Then you are either not using the Firefox Add-on SDK or you are trying to use `require()` from a content script.

Comment: @WladimirPalantᛜ :( yes this is a content script. Actually I am running embedded Youtube player on a page and want some buttons to play/pause it from any tab.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: Content scripts don't have privileges, they cannot manipulate tabs or do anything like that. They have to send a message and ask main extension code to do things for them. Just search, there are plenty of questions here handling that topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var { getTabForId, getTabContentWindow } = require ("sdk/tabs/utils");
var tab = require("tabs").activeTab;
var window = getTabContentWindow (getTabForId(tab.id));
var content = window.document.body.innerHTML;
```

But maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570049/firefox-add-on-get-the-tab-body-content/8573135#8573135) is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the body of the currently-selected tab using the following (after `DOMContentLoaded`):

```
gBrowser.contentDocument.body.innerHTML
```

**Note**: This only works in a standard extension, not in the SDK.

Comment: Nice one, where i get the variable gBrownser?

Comment: This question related specifically to the SDK, so typical extension patterns like yours will not work. Unfortunately the actualy solution ( see below ) is a bit more complex.

Comment: @canuckistani: I added the SDK tag when this answer was already posted, the OP didn't really make it clear - so I think that -1 isn't justified here.

Comment: Wladimir - ah, ok. Wish I could take it back, but I waited too long. @lwburk - sorry!

Comment: @canuckistani - I edited, which I think will allow you to retract your vote, if you want. No worries either way, as I was clearly mistaken.