# Define abstract class method argument Enum<E> for multiple values

Tags: java, enumeration, abstract

I have a question.
How I can define an Enum type for multiple static classes with a different object as Enum?

Example:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public Enum<?> AbstractMethod();
}

public class StaticClass extends AbstractClass
{
    public enum en
    {
        FOO3,
        FOO4
    }

    @Override
    public Enum<en>[] AbstractMethod()
    {
        return en.values();
    }
}

public class StaticClass2 extends AbstractClass
{

    public enum en
    {
        FOO1,
        FOO2
    }

    @Override
    public Enum<en>[] AbstractMethod()
    {
        return en.values();
    }
}
```

But that code throws an error:
The method `public boolean AbstractMethod(Enum<ObjectX> en1)` dosn't exsist in AbstractClass (X is the Number of the Object)

Doing this it works but throws RawTypes warning:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public Enum[] AbstractMethod();
}

public class StaticClass extends AbstractClass
{
    public enum en
    {
        FOO3,
        FOO4
    }

    @Override
    public Enum[] AbstractMethod()
    {
        return en.values();
    }
}

public class StaticClass2 extends AbstractClass
{

    public enum en
    {
        FOO1,
        FOO2
    }

    @Override
    public Enum[] AbstractMethod()
    {
        return en.values();
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost times I can't find what I'm looking for, I don't have  time to test each code and vote up if it works

Comment: [This answer seemed to work just fine for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8573135/451590).

Comment: You don't have time to figure out which answers helped you, but you expect us to take the time to help you?

Comment: Don Roby, You don't read right? Just the first post and comment. I saw almost awnsers not was I looking for, i dont tested it then i can't rate whitout test or is better press + whitout testing codes?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

Enum:

```
public enum Fruits {
    APPLE, ORANGE;
}
```

Classes:

```
public static abstract class Parent {

    public abstract <E extends Enum<?>> void printEnum(final E e);

}

public static class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    public <E extends Enum<?>> void printEnum(final E e) {
        System.out.println(e.name());
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
new Child().printEnum(Fruits.ORANGE); // Prints ORANGE
```

Comment: I mean define an Enum in an Abstract Class who can be use by multiple objects as Enum type, example:

`public Enum<?>[] getCos();` in the abstract class

`public Enum<Object1>[] getCos(){ ... }` in any static class than Override the Enum in the abstract class and same in another classes whit another enum objects. (I will change the first post).